# Why is my code showing only a white screen?

Tags: python, qt-designer, pyside2

I used qt-desiger and translated the code to python with

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\Scripts\pyside2-uic.exe -g python -o C:\test1.py C:\test.ui
```

I tried to run it and that’s what I got

```
from PySide2.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint,
    QRect, QSize, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide2.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QFont,
    QFontDatabase, QIcon, QLinearGradient, QPalette, QPainter, QPixmap,
    QRadialGradient)
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *

from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication,QWidget
import sys

class Ui_MainWindow(QWidget):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(764, 604)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.centralwidget.setEnabled(True)
        self.centralwidget.setTabletTracking(False)
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(u"gridLayout")
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalSpacer = QSpacerItem(20, 142, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        self.gridLayout.addItem(self.verticalSpacer, 0, 1, 1, 1)

        self.horizontalSpacer = QSpacerItem(254, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Minimum)

        self.gridLayout.addItem(self.horizontalSpacer, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.widget = QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setObjectName(u"widget")
        self.widget.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(239, 41, 41);")
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")
        self.label = QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label.setObjectName(u"label")
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(21)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)

        self.textEdit = QTextEdit(self.widget)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName(u"textEdit")
        self.textEdit.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit)


        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.widget, 1, 1, 1, 1)

        self.verticalSpacer_2 = QSpacerItem(20, 141, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        self.gridLayout.addItem(self.verticalSpacer_2, 2, 1, 1, 1)

        self.horizontalSpacer_2 = QSpacerItem(254, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Minimum)

        self.gridLayout.addItem(self.horizontalSpacer_2, 1, 2, 1, 1)

        self.gridLayout.setRowStretch(0, 1)
        self.gridLayout.setRowStretch(2, 1)
        self.gridLayout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        self.gridLayout.setColumnStretch(2, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setObjectName(u"menubar")
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 764, 22))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.label.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Text", None))
    # retranslateUi

my = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Ui_MainWindow()
window.show()

my.exec_()
sys.exit(0)
```

This code gives me only a white screen and should give.

[image]

Comment: @eyllanesc the code from the response causes an error `C:\Users\user>python"C:/test1.py"Traceback (most recent call last):File"C:/test1.py",line 5,in <module>baseUIClass,baseUIWidget=uic.loadUiType("test.ui") File"C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\__ init__.py",line191,in loadUiType from PyQt5 import QtWidgets ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module was not found.`

Comment: from *PyQt5* import QtWidgets? PyQt5 or PySide2? Who told you to use the solution of the accepted answer? Have you read my answer? My answer is generic does not depend on PyQt5 or PySide2

Comment: Applying my solution to your case you get the following code:  https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/57cfb89685c4174f02bf7139120bb617